# How to call one drive API to get token?

Tags: rest, logic, postman, onedrive

I am creating an aplplication where I need to get the authentication token.
For the same I am referring 'Token flow' as suggested here :

https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#token-flow

Here is my request :

[image]

What changes I should make in my request to get the output correctly?